# Can't fetch data from ArrayList

Tags: java, android

I made a code to fetch information from an text file, but it always fails at getting data from the array. If I manually put in a number it works, otherwise it crashes.

Here the code:

```
 public void reload () {
        File file = new File(((Context)this).getExternalFilesDir(null), "Worktime.txt");


        StringBuilder text = new StringBuilder();



        try {
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
            String line;

            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                text.append(line);
                text.append('\n');
            }
            br.close();
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e("tk.spyfly.Worktime", "Unable to read the Worktime.txt file.");
        }


        Scanner s = new Scanner(text.toString());

        list.clear();

        while (s.hasNext()){
            list.add(s.next());
        }
        s.close();
String current;
int worktimetoday=0;

        int i = list.size();
        int count = 0;
        while (count != i){
        count= count +1;
        current = list.get(count);
        current.replace(getString(R.string.workstart) + " ","");
        current.replace(getString(R.string.workstop) + " ","");
        Calendar cs = Calendar.getInstance();
            cs.getTime();
           int year = cs.YEAR;
           int month = cs.MONTH;
            int day = cs.DAY_OF_MONTH;
Date date;
            SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd kk:mm:ss zzz yyyy");

            try {

                date = formatter.parse(current);
                cs.setTime(date);


            } catch (ParseException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();

            }


        int workstart = cs.DAY_OF_MONTH;
            int workyear = cs.YEAR;
            int workmonth = cs.MONTH;
            int workstartmin = cs.MINUTE;
            int workstarth = cs.HOUR_OF_DAY;

        if ((count+1) != i){
            count=count+1;
            if (workyear == year & workmonth == month & day == workstart){
            current = list.get(count);
                current.replace(getString(R.string.workstart) + " ","");
                current.replace(getString(R.string.workstop) + " ","");

                try {

                    date = formatter.parse(current);
                    cs.setTime(date);


                } catch (ParseException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();

                }

            int workend = cs.DAY_OF_YEAR;
            int workendmin = cs.MINUTE;
            int workendh = cs.HOUR_OF_DAY;

if (workend==workstart){
    int workendtime = workendh * 60 + workendmin;
    int workstarttime = workstarth * 60 + workstartmin;

worktimetoday = worktimetoday + (workendtime - workstarttime);
}else {
    int workstarttime = workstarth * 60 + workstartmin;

    worktimetoday = worktimetoday + (1440 - workstarttime);

}}}}

        TextView tw = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
        tw.setText(getString(R.string.worked)+ " "+ worktimetoday + " min.");
        }
```

This is the console error:

```
04-16 20:51:02.420  19544-19544/tk.spyfly.worktime E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: tk.spyfly.worktime, PID: 19544
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{tk.spyfly.worktime/tk.spyfly.worktime.Overview}: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 42, size is 42
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2237)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2286)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1246)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:212)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5135)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:878)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
            at de.robv.android.xposed.XposedBridge.main(XposedBridge.java:132)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 42, size is 42
            at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:255)
            at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:308)
            at tk.spyfly.worktime.Overview.reload(Overview.java:79)
            at tk.spyfly.worktime.Overview.onCreate(Overview.java:164)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2201)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2286)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1246)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:212)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5135)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:878)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
            at de.robv.android.xposed.XposedBridge.main(XposedBridge.java:132)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: In Java, when you want/need to traverse each element from a `List`, use the enhanced `for` loop (commonly known as foreach) rather than using `list#get(index)`. Apart of this, there are several errors in your code.

Comment: Fixed using changing count=count+1;

        if (count != i){

Answer (score 1):

```
while (count != i){
```

should be:

```
while (count != i-1){
```

now counts gets equal to the list size, next you add 1 to count. Count will be bigger than the list size. So you get an outofbounds exception

Answer (score 0):

The relevant lines in the output are:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 42, size is 42
       at tk.spyfly.worktime.Overview.reload(Overview.java:79)
```

This means that in line 79 of your `Overview` class, you try to access the element 43 of a collection with 42 items.

The problem is in this snippet:

```
int i = list.size();
int count = 0;
while (count != i) {
  count = count + 1;
  current = list.get(count);
  // ...
}
```

Just imagine how `count` is increased from loop to loop. You’ll never access the first element (index 0), and you’ll try to access an element that does not exist (index `i + 1`). You should move the incrementation of `count` at the end of your `while` loop to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

```
    int i = list.size();
    int count = 0;
    while (count != i){
    count= count +1;
```

the list index starts on 0 and end on "size-1", in this loop, you skip the first item (index 0) and try to read the index 42 (that doesn't exist) :

```
Caused by: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 42, size is 42
```

you could move the increment to the end of the loop (the index 0 would be read, and the 42 wouldn't)

Answer (score 0):

### What you are doing wrong

You are saving list.size() to a variable i (value 42).
Then you have a counter that starts at 0 and with the `while( count != i )`, meaning you are trying to do the loop 43 times instead of 42, hence the IndexOutOfBoundsException.

### Solution

You are making it more complicated than you have to. 
Instead of saving list.size() and have a counter to be used in a while loop, you should use the Java foreach loop.

See [this example](http://www.java2s.com/Code/JavaAPI/java.util/foreachloopforArrayList.htm).

```
for (int val : collection) { // for each int value in collection...
   // ...do something
}
```

### Tip

However, if you need best performance (fastest possible), read this:

[Performance comparison of different for loops in java](http://howtodoinjava.com/2013/03/26/performance-comparison-of-different-for-loops-in-java/)